# Sort a merged file by second field in a reverse order

Tags: linux, unix

I have merged two files into one file and I am trying to sort the merged file but it looks like I am missing something because one of the files that I Have merged is empty.
Below I show the description of the input and output that I have done:

```
  File1 has this data:
    John#Smith#3400#2000.00
    Blue#Light##2300#9000.00
    John#Smith#3400#2000.00
    Hidey#George#1000#2000.00
    Blue#Light##2300#9000.00
    Trasy#Brown#2000#4000.00
    Hidey#George#1000#2000.00

 1_ I looked for unique values by using this command and stored the output in a new file:
   $ uniq -u File1 > File2 
   and the output of File2 is empty because there were not unique values in File1

 2_ I looked for duplicate values by using this command and stored the output in a new file:
   $ uniq -d File1 > File3
    Here I got the unique values and I stored them in File3

 3_ I combined the two files (File2 and File3)
    Here I got the unique values and I stored them in File3
 4_ When I came to merge File2 with File3
    I used this command: cat File2 File3 > File4
   I got a result as showing below:
  -----------------------------------
  |$      John#Smith#3400#2000.00   |
  |$      Hidey#George#1000#2000.00 |
  |$      Blue#Light##2300#9000.00  |
  |$      Trasy#Brown#2000#4000.00  |
  |$      Hidey#George#1000#2000.00 |
  -----------------------------------
```

That means the two files were merged and the space on the left side happens because of the empty file.

I need help in sorting File4 by the second field and in reverse order.
  I have tried this command: 
   **$sort -k2,2 -r File4**
  I did not see a different display of data order and it just reversed it. 
How to sort two merged files with respect of that one of them is empty and caused a space in the new file.

Comment: does this work on your system?  `sort -t# -rk2 File4`

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly thank you. What does the -t# do in the code? @Milag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -t# -rk2 File4
```

-t#  uses # as a field-separator instead of the default

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.